# An integral of the modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a Dini-continuous function on $B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball. Dini-continuity means 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\omega_f(r)}{r}\mathrm{d}r<\infty
$$
where $\omega_f(r)=\sup_{|x-y|<r}|f(x)-f(y)|$ is the modulus of continuity.

I want to know whether the following statement is true:
$$
\lim_{d\rightarrow0^+}d\int_{d}^1\frac{\omega_f(r)}{r^2}\mathrm{d}r=0
$$

Any hint will help. The problem come from an apriori estimate for the second derivates of the solutions $u$ for Poisson's equation $\Delta u=f$, which is used to prove the existence of $C^2$ solution if $f$ is Dini-continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result follows immediately from Dominated Convergence Theorem since $d \frac {\omega_f(r)} {r^2}$ is dominated by $\frac {\omega_f(r)} {r}$ on $(d,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $r = 1/t$. Then

$$\int_d^1 \frac{\omega_f(r)}{r^2}\,dr = \int_1^{1/d} \omega_f(1/t)\,dt.$$

Since $t \mapsto \omega_f(1/t)$ tends to $0$ for $t \to \infty$, its averages also tend to $0$. With epsilons: let $\varepsilon > 0$. There is a $T$ such that $\omega_f(1/t) < \varepsilon$ for $t > T$. Then

$$\frac{1}{S-1}\int_1^S \omega_f(1/t)\,dt = \frac{1}{S-1}\int_1^T \omega_f(1/t)\,dt + \frac{1}{S-1}\int_T^S \omega_f(1/t)\,dt < \frac{T-1}{S-1}\omega_f(1) + \frac{S-T}{S-1}\varepsilon$$

for $S > T$, and the right hand side is smaller than $2\varepsilon$ for

$$S > 1 + \frac{T-1}{\varepsilon}\omega_f(1).$$

Since $d < \frac{1}{\frac{1}{d}-1}$ it follows that

$$\lim_{d\to 0^+} d\int_d^1 \frac{\omega_f(r)}{r^2}\,dr = 0.$$

We didn't even need Dini-continuity, uniform continuity (that is, $\omega_f(r) \to 0$ for $r \to 0^+$) suffices.